# I Need a Cure for a Ghost

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You're *dead,* don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!
You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.
Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!
Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the answer is...

> fingernails/hangnails

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Fingernails aren't really alive. They also "hang" and can be very annoying.

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> Others can sometimes tell what you have been doing by the state of your fingernails (such as clawing in the dirt)

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> Fingernails start from under the skin, behind the cuticle (hence the "cute")

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> Fingernails have no nerve endings, and are typically clear. When you pull off a hangnail, you might let out a scream!

The cure:

> Nail clippers, or as @Manoj Kumar points out, a maniCURE!

Comment: Nail clippers? :) I think the title gave it half away.

Comment: This is correct! Kudos @ManojKumar as well. For the "telling part," I was going for Rot13 [svatreanvy qeht grfgvat](https://www.google.com/search?ei=e6A7W9KoKMLBzgL38oHgDA&q=fingernail+drug+testing&oq=fingernail+drug+testing&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30k1l7.13349713.13349910.0.13350349.3.3.0.0.0.0.169.169.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.168....0.NqArMKWLECg). I'll mark this as accepted in a little while...

Answer (score 6):

I think its:

> Our own Soul.

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Our soul isn't something alive. Its just a belief we have in our mind.

You've garnered my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> Its a belief that our soul knows even our deepest secrets and nothing is hidden from it and yet it doesn't makes a sound about it.

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> We usually think that our soul resides in our body under our skin.

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> We can't feel our soul nor can we see it yet it tells us things in between good and bad sometimes.

Comment: Nice, but I'm going more for meta*phors,* not meta*physics.* :)

Comment: @Chowzen ok will look forward for it.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Memories/Thoughts?

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Memories/Thoughts are not alive but they stick with you.

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> They hold your secrets but no one can hear them but you. Thinking/remembering them is a retelling to yourself.

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> Sometimes you keep thinking the same thoughts, they won't leave you alone, or you keep flashing back to certain memories that bother you. This seems helpful, but in this situation, they are not.

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> They don't care how you feel, you are going to think/remember them anyways. They are intangible. Your thoughts/memories can seem too loud at times and it's all you can focus on.

Title: I need a cure for a ghost

> Past actions or thoughts that haunt you can be seen as a ghost.

Answer (score 3):

Made me think of

> Tattoos

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Dead ink. After some years, some people want to get rid of them

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> Tattoos are often something very personal and can tell a lot about the ones having them, without making a sound.

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> Obviously under the skin. At the time of making, one might have thought of them as cute.

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> Unfeeling, sure; it's just ink. Transparent maybe... close enough, that's the only hang up. And the wish for it being mute, again: some people deeply regret having tattoos.

The "cure":

> Lazers!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, wrong and I love it:

> GladOS from Portal

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> She is unliving, and even dead after Portal 1. And, as Ricky says, she hangs around!

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> While transmitting test data to whatever database aperture fills, it makes no sound, as it's just data transmission

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> She may be responsible for a number of Chell's implants, like the super boots. She definitely thinks she, or at least her cold manners, are cute.

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> The protagonist might have felt better if GladOS were mute. Her being unfeeling is evident. The "transparent" could refer to her making harsh comments that are true.

Comment: Sorry, "The Cake is a **Lie**."

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Hair?

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Hair is dead, and some people don't want it on their skin so they shave it.

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound.

> You may tell your "beard hair" everything.

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> The hair grows from under your skin, and it is soft, and fuzzy.

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> Hair does not have feeling, and depending on your hair color and can be pretty light. Also hair can tell you when you are scared and it raises up.

Comment: Very close! Find another couple of hints (including title) and it will be more transparent than hair is...

Comment: If this is very close, finger nails should be the answer. Mani _cure_ and Pedi _cure_.

Answer (score 0):

> Memory

You're dead, don't you see it? Just stop hanging around!

> Memory is not from present and some memories are distracting us

You tell all my secrets, yet make not a sound

> I am the only person who know every thing that happens with me

Gotten under my skin—you think that you're cute!

> Memories inside my brains and anyway those are under me

Unfeeling, transparent, why can't you be mute?

> Memories are not a touchable thing so there are no feel and there are no color but sometimes we will remember those so those are not mute

The cure

> Get rid of unnecessary memory

Comment: Hi there, you should look at the given answer before giving your answer as the answer you've given is already submitted by someone. Plus the answer should be enclosed within a spoiler tag. Here, I've fixed it for you. Finally you've to give proper explanation as of why you think that this in your answer.

Comment: Hi @Maniraj is it really not memory???

Comment: @Tharani I'm afraid not, OP has already confirmed that the top-voted answer is correct (but hasn't marked it as correct yet). Nice try, though! Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.